# Weird Bootstrap bugs (table and navbar)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, border

## **Table bug fixed: I was missing thead and tbody tags!**

I have a weird problem with Bootstrap. Everything works perfectly fine, but when I try to use table-hover class it just does not work. Also, the table has upper border: http://gyazo.com/796c5bb99058c0d07e8ece8f54790399.png

Also, when I resize the Chrome browser, the navigation bar looks like this:
http://gyazo.com/cb7842b71d7a6e63eb0d5ce3f0b52902.png
instead of normal 'mobile' look on getbootstrap.com site.

I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Code:

```
<table id='keytable' class='table table-hover'>
<tr><th>sv_licensenum</th><th>Type</th><th>Key</th><th>Description<‌​/th></tr>
<tr><td>0</td><td>Ranked</td><td>alrCOdo8PsFUur6iZmIlESd7</td><td>test2<‌​/td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Ranked</td><td>VLnNg25kSZRB4IzNpufu0qIs</td><td>test45‌​6</td></tr>
</table>
```

id="keytable" is not specified in any external non-Bootstrap CSS file/code. it is only used for Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting the file carefully I have figured the reason for this weird behavior.

You need to remove the style you have defined in you html. This is the reason the navbar gets a padding when you reach 979px or less. You can consider defining this through @media or media-query

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px; 
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

And then you have to remove the style

```
nav-collapse collapse
```

This will hide whatever you put inside this.

Read http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand the limitation, if negative marking comes with an explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have also included the required bootstrap js files. I did not get any issues when I tested the code you provided.

Comment: I have: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>, <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>,  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>. @pallab

Comment: Would be helpful if you share your code. or a scale down version where the problem could be replicated.

Comment: Indeed. It is happening for the media query attached on the bootstap-responsive.min.css. The moment width goes below 980px the entire navbar is getting changed.
Suggestion: change the responsive.min to responsive.css for debugging purpose. and you can inspect the change in the developer console. Then apply / overwrite style as needed.
Will be investigating this Further.

Comment: And the table thingy? @pallab

Comment: I think you can get rid of that by overriding the styles defined by bootstarp. Just create a custom css and include after the bootstarp is included. You need to change this style 
`.table th, .table td {
    border-top: 0
}`

Comment: i fixed it, i was missing thead and tbody tags.. :P